# I am facing errors linking a variable between PHP & JS in this HTML code

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs

I have this PHP & JS Code with me, whose task is to post a variable message to a function :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script language="php">
    $somevar = $_GET['id'];
</script>

<script>
var msg = <?php echo $somevar; ?>;
var ThunkableWebviewerExtension = {
    postMessage: function (message) {
        if (window.ReactNativeWebView) {
            window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(message);
        } else {
            window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');
        }
    }
}

ThunkableWebviewerExtension.postMessage(msg);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is, define a variable in PHP, fetch it's value in JS, and post it to the function. The reason I am using PHP is because I can get those values with PHP only. So, all I need to do is, get that PHP value into a JS variable and use it further.

When I run this code, nothing happens - but if I remove the whole PHP thing, and set the JS's `var msg` to a absolute string (like `var msg = 'hi';`) then it works. So, I think there's some problem with the linking of PHP and JS - can you please help me with this?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: NOTE: Script tags <script language="php"></script> and ASP tags <% %> are removed from PHP 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not wrap PHP in `<script>` tags. You should wrap PHP in `<?php ?>`, so you need to swap this:

```
 <script language="php">
    $somevar = $_GET['id'];
 </script>
```

with this:

```
<?php
$somevar = $_GET['id'];
?>
```

And the rest of the code seems to be OK.

Comment: Thanks, @Marcello! Where should I place this PHP code? Should I just switch tags & let the code stay where it is (above JS code)?

Comment: Thanks @Marcello, but I am facing an error from the editor here : `Expected tag name. Got '?' instead. (HTML doesn't support processing instructions.)` What should I do?

Comment: is your file a .php file or .html file?

Comment: it's a .html file. Thanks

Comment: it must be a PHP file if you want to run PHP in it. you should change the file extension to .php

Comment: Ok. So do I just need to change the extension of the file, nothing else at all? Thanks!

Comment: that could be the problem, but you need to run PHP in a virtual server, PHP is not a front-end language, it's a back-end language and you need a server to compile it. The browser can't read PHP.